# 'super' keyword unexpected here

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get 'super' keyword unexpected here when I try to call an extended function.

```
handleLogin(data, client) {
    logger.write('Login initiated');

    var xml = libxmljs.parseXml(data);
    var nick = (xml.get('//nick')).text();
    var pass = (xml.get('//pword')).text();

    super.database.getPlayer(nick, function(err, player) {
        if(player) {
            super.database.updateColumn(player.id, 'loginKey', loginKey);
        }
    });
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
            super.database.updateColumn(player.id, 'loginKey', loginKey);
```

I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: This is because `super` variable is out of `handleLogin` function scope accessibility. Where do you define `super` variable?

Comment: super is a reserved word for classes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Comment: This is a method inside a class. I'm defining it in the constructor of another class that is extended in this method's class..

Comment: use an arrow function instead of `function(err, player){...}` or store a reference to `super.database` outside the previously mentioned callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an arrow function as the callback to preserve the scope for the context-specific keyword [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super):

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, ms)
})

// dumb example
class SlowArray extends Array {
  push (value) {
    return wait(Math.random() * 100 + 100)
      .then(() => {
        // arrow function with super
        return super.push(value)
      })
  }
}

var array = new SlowArray()

array.push(5).then(length => {
  console.log('done:', length, `[${array}]`)
})

console.log('waiting...', length, `[${array}]`)
```

So in your example, that would be:

```
super.database.getPlayer(nick, (err, player) => {
    if (player) {
        super.database.updateColumn(player.id, 'loginKey', loginKey);
    }
});
```